# Get the record number for id (SQLite) Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Mastering SQLite, faced with a problem.

I need to get the record number for the record id ...

Suppose the table "mytable" 3 records:

1 entry: "id = 4";

Record 2: "id = 5";

3 record: "id = 6";

How can I find the number of the record with id = 5, for example ...

Can you give an example with the code, and then nothing happens! (

Comment: What is "the record number"? Are you referring to `ROWID`?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. Yes, ROWID;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `rawQuery("SELECT ROWID FROM yourtablename WHERE id = ?", args)` on your `SQLiteDatabase`, where `args` is a `String[]` containing one `String` with the `id` that you are looking for, and `yourtablename` is your table name. You will get a `Cursor` back containing the `ROWID`.